# Automating new dates in google sheets / scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to automate creating a calendar with google script. I am taking data from a sheet where I have to enter events weekly. In my sheet, it is formatted to enter into google calendar. That script works well, but I want to automate my week of date. I have it set to take that Monday date, and add 7 days for a new week. It worked for 10/26 to 11/2, but when it goes to the following week, it reverts to 10/9 instead of 11/9 and the rest of the dates are all October and not November. I can't figure out the issue at all. I'm not the best at coding, but have found and manipulated most of the codes found online

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14JQ-qqZ4eIl2xKuBjzSHSyC-4fV_yVxih9qUIwLGfNA/edit?usp=sharing

```js
function changeDate() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 
  var startDate = new Date(sheet.getRange("A2").getValues());
  var secondDate = new Date();
   
  secondDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+7);
  
  Logger.log(startDate);
  sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(secondDate);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [getDate()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp) returns you only the day of the month, not the full date

you will be better of converting your date into ms with [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) and add the equivalent of 7 days in ms:

```
  var startDate = new Date(sheet.getRange("A2").getValues());
  var secondDate = new Date(startDate.getTime()+7*24*3600*1000);
  sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(secondDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That makes it go from 10/26 to 12/3...

Comment: I just verified once again and it works correctly for me.

Comment: You can do this `secondDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+7);` like this `var secondDate=new Date(starttDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(),startDate.getDate()+7)`

Comment: Actually I believe it's a DST issue. It's still weird in that it goes from 10/26 to 11/1 23:00 timestamp. If I manually change it to 11/2, everything works fine.

Any ideas to prevent or account for that?

Comment: @Cooper That was it! Thanks for your help! Why does that work and the original code doesnt?

Comment: Hi Chris, I just checked: your locale is United States where daylight saving time begins the first of November - so this is the issue indeed. You can work around it, e.g. by retrieving `getTimezoneOffset()` and implement a correction in case there was a DST change between the two dates, but probably @Cooper's solution would be the more elegant in this case.